UK visitor visa for an OCI card holder with US passport
My son is a US citizen by birth and also a valid US passport holder but living with me in India on an OCI card for over 10 years. We are planning to travel to the UK on a vacation. Does my son require a UK standard visitor visa? (The Gov.UK website states that US passport holders do not require a visa, but does not state anything about US citizens with OCI card). I just do not want to be in a position where we land in the UK and they deny entry to my son since we have travelled from India).
Thanks,
Ralf

The OCI status plays (almost) no role anywhere outside India. US citizens can visit the UK visa-free. No need to worry. Actually, you don't have to advertise the fact that your son has an OCI card to the UK border officials. If they ask whether your son has one, tell the truth, but it's not likely they would care.


The Gov.UK website states that US passport holders do not require a visa, but does not state anything about US citizens with OCI card.

That is because there no document that cancels the visa exemption for visa-exempt travelers.  US citizens are visa exempt, period.

I just do not want to be in a position where we land in the UK and they deny entry to my son since we have travelled from India.

The point of departure and the details of the itinerary are not relevant.  Only the use of a visa-exempt passport is relevant.
Visa exempt travelers can obtain visas, however, if they want to.  If you're extremely nervous and if you aren't particularly bothered by the bureaucratic hassle, fees, and other costs of getting a visa, by all means do it.  But there really isn't any reason to do it other than to calm your nerves (if indeed you are still nervous after reading these answers).
Another possible source of reassurance is https://traveldoc.aero although it does not seem to recognize the OCI per se.  I entered it as a residence permit issued by India.  The site allows you to enter a round trip or multiple city itinerary along with multiple passports, residence permits, and other documents, and shows whether the documents are sufficient for the trip.  As expected, it reports that no visa is necessary for a US citizen with a US passport and an Indian residence permit to fly from India to the UK and back.
